# Unity | Which child sprite did I clicked?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, sprite

I made and empty game object that I use for a container for my sprites, which are my buttons.
I want to know which sprite I just clicked with one script on my container so I can add more buttons later and not have to alter the code.

Comment: Are you using the unity UI or you want to use OnMouseDown Messages?

Comment: OnMouseDown Messages

Comment: If that is a UI then the best practice is to use uGUI instead. What you are doing is incorrect for a UI. See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html

Answer (score 0):

Many way can doing that.
my solution:

i Create `Button` Script to handling the `OnMouseDown` but i don't add it to child because i add it with the Container code.

then in `ButtonContainer` script get all child and add BoxCollider2D and Button to theme and important part is Adding your listener(DoSomthing method).

Done. :)

1. create a script Button:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class Button : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SpriteRenderer sr;
    public MouseDownEvent mouseDown = new MouseDownEvent();

    void Awake(){
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    void OnMouseDown(){
        mouseDown.Invoke(sr);
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class MouseDownEvent : UnityEvent<SpriteRenderer> { }
```

2.create a script for ButtonCountainer

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class ButtonContainer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        // get all child
        var childs = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

        // add button class to them
        for (int i = 0; i < childs.Length; i++) {
            // child element
            var go = childs[i].gameObject;
            // add boxcolliser2d. (child must have collider to invoke the OnMouseDown Message)
            go.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
            // add button script to them
            var b = go.AddComponent<Button>();
            // do everything you want with this event
            b.mouseDown.AddListener(DoSomthing);
        }
    }
    // every time this gameObject invoke sr = sprite renderer of the that gameObject
    private void DoSomthing(SpriteRenderer sr)
    {
        Debug.Log(sr.name);
    }
}
```

3. create GameObject and add ButtonCountainer to that.
4. now add sprites as child.
5. end. we have lunch.